# MIPS32, Using the Stack for recursive multiplication, there is no output

Tags: mips, mips32

So my test case is 7 for the multiplicand and 9 for the multiplier, I am trying to use Recursive Multiplication by using repeated addition, recursively. I'm a beginner in stacks in regards to MIPS so what could be the reason why nothing is wanting to output?

I am required to use $a0 -> Multiplicand, $a1 -> Multiplier, and $v0 -> Product

```
.text
main:

  #Printing out prompt1
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, prompt1
  syscall
  #Getting user input -> Multiplicand
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  move $a0, $v0
  
  #Printing out prompt2
  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, prompt2
  syscall
  #Getting user input -> Multiplier
  li $v0, 5
  syscall
  move $a1, $v0
  
  #Loop
  mult:
     addiu $sp,$sp, -8
     sw $a0, 4($sp)
     sw $ra, 0($sp)
     bne $a0, 1, else
     add $v0, $v0, 0
     j exit
  else: 
     sub $a1, $a1, 1
     jal mult
  exit: 
     lw $a0, 4($sp)
     add $v0, $v0, $a0
     sw $v0, 4($sp)
     addiu $sp, $sp, 8
     jr $ra
     
  lw $v0, multiplicand
  li $v0, 1
  la $a0, multiplicand
  syscall
  
  #Ending Program
  li $v0, 10
  syscall

.data
prompt1: .asciiz "Enter the multiplicand: "
prompt2: .asciiz "Enter the multiplier: "
multiplicand: .space 101
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?  Use single step to see where it goes wrong.  Try it first on smaller inputs like 2 x 2.

Comment: Also, study simple functions: their implementation and invocation, both, from your coursework or elsewhere.  Note especially the transfer of control back and forth.

Comment: It seems its going wrong on sw $a0, 4($sp), I changed it to sw $a0, 0($sp) and didn't store $ra but it seems to bring the same error "ADDRESS OUT OF RANGE" So Im assuming an overflow?

Comment: You need to study some correct function implementations, and how they are called e.g. from main.  You have come up with an unusual (and broken) control flow that isn't a recursive function.